# Can the principle of ikar and tafel apply to wearing special clothing for shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, clothing

If the majority of the clothes worn on Shabbat are special and set aside to be worn only on Shabbat and yom tovim can one mix in a minority of clothing usually worn during the week?

For example one has a special suit, tie, shoes and coat for Shabbat can he add to the outfit a winter hat worn during the week along with a warm sweater also worn during the week?

Can one do this le'hathilla or is it preferable for all the clothes to be specially designated for Shabbat/Yom Yov?

--

[Rabbi Eli Mansour](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=604) addresses the question of wearing weekday shoes:

> The Ben Ish Hai (Rav Yosef Haim of Baghdad, 1833-1909), in his work
>   Rab Pe’alim, addresses the question of whether one must have a special
>   pair of shoes designated for wearing on Shabbat. He proves from a
>   number of sources that one is not required to have a special pair of
>   shoes for Shabbat, though certainly one should polish his shoes and
>   make sure they look presentable for Shabbat. The Kaf Ha’haim writes
>   that one who can afford to purchase a special pair of shoes for
>   Shabbat should preferably do so, though this is not required according
>   to the strict Halacha.

But I wonder if shoes are the exception.

Comment: I don't understand. Is there some reason one might wear different clothes _Shabas_ from weekdays? Can you [edit] that reason into the question?

Comment: Why would one belt differ from one shirt?

Comment: A suit is essential and a belt is not? I don't follow. Belts hold up pants. Suits are pretty functionless and silly. How are you defining essential and why is that category relevant?

Comment: Me belt is unnecessary. If the pants are the right size they don't move around.

Comment: @doubleaa perhaps ikar and tafel can help. If the majority of the clothing is special for shabbat can some tafel clothing be worn with them that is also worn during the week?

Comment: Your suit jacket is unnecessary too if you wear a shirt. And don't get me started about ties...

Comment: Ikar tafel is a good question that I can understand. If you want to ask it please feel free to.